# ¿Como hacer un hola mundo en ensamblador Nasm en windows?

Tags: windows, x86, nasm, programación-bajo-nivel

Quisiera saber cómo hacer un *hola mundo* en nasm con el sistema operativo Windows 8 64-bits.

¿O deberia cambiar a Tasm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el código para hacer un `hola mundo` en `asm` con TASM es así

```
datos SEGMENT
cadena DB "Hola Mundo$"
datos ENDS
codigo SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:codigo,ds:datos
inicio :MOV AX, datos
        MOV DS, AX
        MOV AH,09h
        MOV DX,offset cadena
        INT 21h
fin: MOV AH,4Ch
        INT 21h
codigo ENDS
END inicio
```

Guardamos en archivo con extensión asm , luego ejecutamos los siguientes comandos situados donde tenemos el archivo asm

1. `TASM namefile.asm`
2. `TLINK namefile`
3. `namefile`

> Para ejecutar esto es necesario tener los siguientes componentes en el mismo directorio del archivo asm :  `DPMILOAD.exe` ,
>   `DPMIMEM.DLL`  , `TD.EXE` , `TLINK.EXE` , `TASM.EXE`

Comment: ¿Tambien podria valer porner los ejecutables en el path?

Comment: Con qué finalidad?

Comment: De que no se coloquen los archivos en cada directorio que quieras compilar

Comment: @Dev.Joel ¿ Todavía se puede usar la `21h` ? Cuantos recuerdos del viejo MS/DOS ...

Comment: Sí , el programa está pensado para un procesador 8086 (noactual).

Comment: .... Y ¿Se podrá hacer en nasm?. @Dev.Joel